# Update column in a group from the same column value

Tags: scala, grouping, updates

I have df:

```
+---+-----+----+----+
| id|group|pick|name|
+---+-----+----+----+
|  1|    1|   0|   a|
|  2|    1|   1|   b|
|  3|    2|   0|   c|
|  4|    2|   0|   d|
|  5|    2|   1|   e|
|  6|    3|   1|   f|
|  7|    3|   0|   g|
|  8|    4|   1|   h|
+---+-----+----+----+
```

Every group has one pick = 1, I want to pick that name for each group, like this:

```
+---+-----+----+----+-----------+
| id|group|pick|name|picked_name|
+---+-----+----+----+-----------+
|  1|    1|   0|   a|          b|
|  2|    1|   1|   b|          b|
|  3|    2|   0|   c|          e|
|  4|    2|   0|   d|          e|
|  5|    2|   1|   e|          e|
|  6|    3|   1|   f|          f|
|  7|    3|   0|   g|          f|
|  8|    4|   1|   h|          h|
+---+-----+----+----+-----------+
```

Can someone please help...Please note that I am very cautious on the performance as I have to do this on a huge data set. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one solution using df and window functions

```
scala> val df = Seq((1,1,0,"a"),(2,1,1,"b"),(3,2,0,"c"),(4,2,0,"d"),(5,2,1,"e"),(6,3,1,"f"),(7,3,0,"g"),(8,4,1,"h")).toDF("id","group","pick","name")
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [id: int, group: int ... 2 more fields]

scala> val df2=df.filter('pick===1).withColumnRenamed("pick","pick2").withColumnRenamed("name","name2")
df2: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [id: int, group: int ... 2 more fields]

scala> df.join(df2,Seq("id","group"),"leftOuter").withColumn("picked_name",max('name2).over(Window.partitionBy('group))).drop("pick2","name2").show
+---+-----+----+----+-----------+
| id|group|pick|name|picked_name|
+---+-----+----+----+-----------+
|  1|    1|   0|   a|          b|
|  2|    1|   1|   b|          b|
|  6|    3|   1|   f|          f|
|  7|    3|   0|   g|          f|
|  8|    4|   1|   h|          h|
|  3|    2|   0|   c|          e|
|  4|    2|   0|   d|          e|
|  5|    2|   1|   e|          e|
+---+-----+----+----+-----------+


scala>
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much!

Comment: For some reason it is slow when it's called in loop, good performance in first call, but get slower and slower in subsequent calls. Probably because of join?

Comment: may be because of loop, not sure why you are using loops and calling df inside that..

Comment: I perform further calculation based on picked_name, and store into picked_name_expr. I need to do this over and over again on a dataframe and during that my "pick" for a group also may get changed